# ggplot2: adding a new feature and forcing it to be in back

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to use ggplot to create a complex plot and then at the very end, I would like to add the word "Draft" to it.  But I would like that word to be in the back, rather than the front.  I know I can have it in the back just adding it first, but this is not what I want.  The reason is, I want to write a custom save function that adds the name of the source file used to create the figure to the x axis and also marks the figure as "Draft" unless a certain flag is set.  My custom function does this, but the word "Draft" is always in front.

Is there some way to tweak just the annotate line below, keeping the order the same, that will put draft behind the sine wave?

```
x = seq(0,100,.1)
d = data.frame(x=x,y=sin(x))

p = ggplot(data=d,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line(size=3,color="grey50")
p = p + annotate("text",x=50,y=0,label="Draft",color="blue",size=40)
print(p)
ggsave(filename = "test_background.pdf")
```

[image]

Comment: why not use `alpha=.2` in your annotate to make it transparent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

before plotting,

```
p$layers <- rev(p$layers)
```